# Error when trying to call an array variable in arithmetic

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I'm trying to create a bash script that performs an arithmetic operation that calls variables from an array, however the program keeps throwing out syntax errors.

Here is the code:

```
#! /system/bin/bash

#Declaring y, L and T
declare -a y=()
declare -a L=()
declare -a T=()
y=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
L[1]=12
T[1]=5

#Finding all Levels of (L) sub t 
ycount=$(( ${#y[@]} + 1 ))                      
begin=1
counter=2

while [ $begin -lt $ycount ]
do                                                                         
     L[$counter]=$( echo "($alpha * ${y[$begin]}) + ((1 - $alpha) *(${L[$begin]} + ${T[$begin]}))" | bc -l)
     begin=$(( $begin + 1 ))
     counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done
```

This happens when you run the code:

```
$ bash /tmp/test.sh
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I'm pretty sure the error is in calling L[$begin] and T[$begin] as when I substitute numbers for these variables I no longer get a syntax error.

Comment: Are you actually using `bash`? Also, `ycount` isn't defined, so you should get an error from `[` in the condition of the `while` loop. `y` and `T` are similarly undefined, as is `L` on the first iteration.

Comment: That said, why are you using `bash` for this kind of numerical data processing?

Comment: i am using bash. ycount is equal to 7 (further up in code). Similarly, L and T are declared as arrays further up in the code.  L[1] and T[1] both have values stored in them.

Comment: Also I'm using bash because Im amending existing code

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis: `counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for that reference. Hopefully it's better now

Comment: `yco` isn't defined, what's it for ?

Comment: also what's the point of using bc for such a simple arithmetic operation ? you can use `$((...))`

Comment: @oguzismail `$((...))` only does integer arithmetic. `alpha` is almost certainly a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: not that mentioned in question

Comment: bc because the values could be decimal

Comment: Thank you very much @chepner and everyone else who took time to try and help me. You guys are doing God's work

Comment: It looks like you may be assuming array indexes start at 1. This is correct in zsh, but bash starts them at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Those are `bc` syntax errors: the `$alpha` variable is uninitialized.

here is what happens when you turn on shell tracing:

```
$ bash -x /tmp/test.sh
+ y=()
+ declare -a y
+ L=()
+ declare -a L
+ T=()
+ declare -a T
+ y=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
+ L[1]=12
+ T[1]=5
+ ycount=7
+ begin=1
+ counter=2
+ '[' 1 -lt 7 ']'
++ bc -l
++ echo '( * 2) + ((1 - ) *(12 + 5))'
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
+ L[$counter]=
+ begin=2
... and so on
```

You are also suffering from "off by one" array indexing errors:

```
$ y=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
$ declare -p y
declare -a y=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6")
# .............^
```

You also never assign to the T array, so as soon as begin > 1, ${T[$begin]} is empty.

Comment: This! Thank you very much. I appreciate the help. The mistake sounds so trivial now. Excuse my ignorance, but is there a good error proofing program I could use?

Comment: There is https://shellcheck.net but that's just for syntax errors. Hard to programmatically identify data errors like these.

Comment: Oh, bash's `-u` setting would help: `set -u` -- that will throw errors for "unbound variables".

Comment: Thank you very much ill take a look at shellcheck. The set manual is intimidating